# Swift: Bring View from Stack View to front

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uikit, uistackview

I got a Stack View with view: 1,2,3,4 and 5

Looking for a method to bring the Image View4 from view4 in the Stack view, above all the other views. The reason I need this is because I am moving the Image View4 over the Image View3 in view3.

I have tried to move view3 over view4 in the view hierarchy, but that just swaps their places in the Stack View.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [UIStackView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview):

> The order of [the views in] the `subviews` array defines the Z-order of the subviews. If the views overlap, subviews with a lower index appear behind subviews with a higher index.

So since all views in the stack view's `arrangedSubviews` array are also in the stack view's `subviews` array, you should be able to use the standard `UIView` APIs to rearrange the views z-order:

- `bringSubview(toFront:)`
- `sendSubview(toBack:)`
- `exchangeSubview(at:withSubviewAt:)`

I don't know whether this is possible to do in Interface Builder or not.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the image from the stack view and add it to the same view that contains the stack view as a subview, using `addSubview(_:)`. That will put it on top of all other views. You could also use `insertSubview(_:aboveSubview:)` to insert it directly above the stack view.

You'll need to add constraints to the new view so that it is positioned where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have IBOutlet property in UIViewController but in view hierarchy it is placed in UIStackView.
So you should use

`stackView.bringSubviewToFront(myView)`

rather then

`self.view.bringSubviewToFront(myView)`