# how to add subview at the background

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uistackview

I have a stackview in which there are 3 items vertically aligned. Now I created a `Uiview` to give it a border and adding that too in stackview to show it as a colored background of with radius corners.

I am successful of creating and attaching a view to the `UIStackview`. But it seems like it is covering all other arranged subviews of `UIStackView`. whereas I want to bring other subviews at front. please help me. here is the code below:

```
extension UIStackView {
    override open var backgroundColor: UIColor? {

        get {
            return super.backgroundColor
        }

        set {

            super.backgroundColor = newValue

            let tag = -9999
            for view in subviews where view.tag == tag {
                view.removeFromSuperview()
            }

            let subView = UIView()
            subView.tag = tag
            subView.backgroundColor = newValue
            subView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            subView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            subView.layer.masksToBounds = true
            subView.layer.borderColor = CommonUtils.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#C2C2C2").cgColor
            subView.layer.borderWidth = 0.35
            self.addSubview(subView)
            subView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
            subView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            subView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            subView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: Bring View from Stack View to front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46780033/swift-bring-view-from-stack-view-to-front)

Comment: `subView.layer.zPosition = -1`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
self.insertSubview(subView, at:0)
```

instead of

```
self.addSubview(subView)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `self.view.bringSubview(toFront: yourView)`